# Why are the column names of data.table changing after adding new columns?

Tags: r, data.table, copy

Strange behaviour of data.table.

```
library(data.table)
d<-data.table(a=1,b=2)
n<-names(d)
d[,c:=3,]
print(n)
```

Output:

```
 [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

This seems rather strange to me. Somehow the vector n is modified when adding columns to d.
Why is that?

Comment: This is probably linked to the fact that `names` is an accessor function returning a pointer to the internal variable used by `data.table` to store column names.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some wrong with data.table. The following will display [1] "a" "b" .

```
library(data.table)
d =data.table(a=1,b=2)
n = names(d)
n = paste(n)  #reproduce the variable
d=d[, c := 1, ]
print(n)
```

result:

```
[1] "a" "b"
```

the internal linkage can be shown here:

```
d =data.table(a=1,b=2)
.Internal(inspect(d))
n = names(d)
.Internal(inspect(n))
d=d[,  := 1, ]
.Internal(inspect(d))
.Internal(inspect(n))
```

result:

```
> d =data.table(a=1,b=2)
> .Internal(inspect(d))
@0x0000026f5ab5c810 19 VECSXP g0c7 [OBJ,NAM(7),ATT] (len=2, tl=1026)
  @0x0000026f5a224ae8 14 REALSXP g0c1 [NAM(7)] (len=1, tl=0) 1
  @0x0000026f5a224d88 14 REALSXP g0c1 [NAM(7)] (len=1, tl=0) 2
ATTRIB:
  @0x0000026f3c235160 02 LISTSXP g0c0 [] 
    TAG: @0x0000026f315c1710 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,NAM(7),LCK,gp=0x6000] "names" (has value)
    @0x0000026f59151a00 16 STRSXP g0c7 [NAM(7)] (len=2, tl=1026)
      @0x0000026f32fd6408 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "a"
      @0x0000026f33382928 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61,ATT] [ASCII] [cached] "b"
    TAG: @0x0000026f315c14e0 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,NAM(7),LCK,gp=0x6000] "row.names" (has value)
    @0x0000026f5969ff28 13 INTSXP g0c1 [] (len=2, tl=0) -2147483648,-1
    TAG: @0x0000026f315c1be0 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,NAM(7),LCK,gp=0x6000] "class" (has value)
    @0x0000026f5ae54a28 16 STRSXP g0c2 [NAM(7)] (len=2, tl=0)
      @0x0000026f34459998 09 CHARSXP g1c2 [MARK,gp=0x61,ATT] [ASCII] [cached] "data.table"
      @0x0000026f316321e0 09 CHARSXP g1c2 [MARK,gp=0x61,ATT] [ASCII] [cached] "data.frame"
    TAG: @0x0000026f3cc83240 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK] ".internal.selfref"
    @0x0000026f3c2351d0 22 EXTPTRSXP g0c0 [NAM(7)] 
> n = names(d)
> .Internal(inspect(n))
@0x0000026f59151a00 16 STRSXP g0c7 [NAM(7)] (len=2, tl=1026)
  @0x0000026f32fd6408 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "a"
  @0x0000026f33382928 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61,ATT] [ASCII] [cached] "b"
> d=d[, c := 1, ]
> .Internal(inspect(d))
@0x0000026f5ab5c810 19 VECSXP g0c7 [OBJ,NAM(7),ATT] (len=3, tl=1026)
  @0x0000026f5a224ae8 14 REALSXP g0c1 [NAM(7)] (len=1, tl=0) 1
  @0x0000026f5a224d88 14 REALSXP g0c1 [NAM(7)] (len=1, tl=0) 2
  @0x0000026f5a332108 14 REALSXP g0c1 [] (len=1, tl=0) 1
ATTRIB:
  @0x0000026f3c235160 02 LISTSXP g0c0 [] 
    TAG: @0x0000026f315c1710 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,NAM(7),LCK,gp=0x6000] "names" (has value)
    @0x0000026f59151a00 16 STRSXP g0c7 [NAM(7)] (len=3, tl=1026)
      @0x0000026f32fd6408 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "a"
      @0x0000026f33382928 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61,ATT] [ASCII] [cached] "b"
      @0x0000026f315c2a28 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61,ATT] [ASCII] [cached] "c"
    TAG: @0x0000026f315c14e0 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,NAM(7),LCK,gp=0x6000] "row.names" (has value)
    @0x0000026f5969ff28 13 INTSXP g0c1 [] (len=2, tl=0) -2147483648,-1
    TAG: @0x0000026f315c1be0 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,NAM(7),LCK,gp=0x6000] "class" (has value)
    @0x0000026f5ae54a28 16 STRSXP g0c2 [NAM(7)] (len=2, tl=0)
      @0x0000026f34459998 09 CHARSXP g1c2 [MARK,gp=0x61,ATT] [ASCII] [cached] "data.table"
      @0x0000026f316321e0 09 CHARSXP g1c2 [MARK,gp=0x61,ATT] [ASCII] [cached] "data.frame"
    TAG: @0x0000026f3cc83240 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK] ".internal.selfref"
    @0x0000026f3c2351d0 22 EXTPTRSXP g0c0 [NAM(7)] 
> .Internal(inspect(n))
@0x0000026f59151a00 16 STRSXP g0c7 [NAM(7)] (len=3, tl=1026)
  @0x0000026f32fd6408 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "a"
  @0x0000026f33382928 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61,ATT] [ASCII] [cached] "b"
  @0x0000026f315c2a28 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61,ATT] [ASCII] [cached] "c"
```

Comment: Nice inspection into the mem info, from which it is easy to understand what happened! +1

Comment: One more comment, it is not "something wrong with data.table". We should follow `data.table`'s philosophy when use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with `data.table`, please be aware of using `copy`. When typing `?data.table::copy` in the console, you will see details like below

> data.table provides functions that operate on objects by reference and
> minimise full object copies as much as possible. Still, it might be
> necessary in some situations to work on an object's copy which can be
> done using DT.copy <- copy(DT). It may also be sometimes useful before
> := (or set) is used to subassign to a column by reference.
>
> A copy() may be required when doing dt_names = names(DT). Due to R's
> copy-on-modify, dt_names still points to the same location in memory
> as names(DT). Therefore modifying DT by reference now, say by adding a
> new column, dt_names will also get updated. To avoid this, one has to
> explicitly copy: dt_names <- copy(names(DT)).

So the issue you met is due to the pointer to the same memory address.

---

Long story short, you should use `n <- copy(names(d))`